# Bootstrap5 input-group with btn-group-vertical

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

As title, I want to create a input-group for number increase/decrease.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.9">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Result

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `py-0` for remove top & bottom padding and `lh-1` for decrease line height of button. Your code should be as below:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.9">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm py-0 lh-1" type="button">+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm py-0 lh-1" type="button">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add p-0 in button so the code will like this :

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.9">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm p-0" type="button">+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm p-0" type="button">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```